# Merging 3 arrays to one base on field

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have three array (is about the data migration)

```
$a = Array
     (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => province
            [1] => 701
            [2] => AA
            [3] => A
        )
   ..
 )
$b = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => district
            [1] => 70101
            [2] => BB
            [3] => B
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => district
            [1] => 70102
            [2] => BB1
            [3] => B1
        )
  ..
  )


$c = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => commune
            [1] => 7010101
            [2] => CC
            [3] => C
        ),
     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => commune
            [1] => 7010102
            [2] => CC1
            [3] => C1
        )
..
)
```

What I want is to merge all `$a` , `$b` , `$c' to become a new array
in this example array that have value`701`is the key of sub array`70101`and`70101`is the key of sub array`7010101`

So the final array may look something like this:

```
$d = array (
                 701=>array(
                       70101=>array(7010101,7010102),
                       70102=>array(7010201,7010202),
                     ),
            )
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far? If your question is how to do this - what I suppose - then you just have to loop through the 3 arrays and check whether the keys of (district, commune) are contained in the upper category e.g. for a district you would check if the key starts with the same 3 digits than the province -> if so: fill your buffer-element -> same with the commune/district.

Comment: I am trying with if (strpos($a,'701') !== false) {
//Do something 
}

Comment: You cannot apply strpos on arrays. Its for strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attempt is like the following:

```
# Your data structure here:
$a = array(
    '701' => 'foo',
    '702' => 'bar',
);

$b = array(
    '70101' => 'foo-foo',
    '70102' => 'foo-bar',
);

$c = array(
    '7010101' => 'foo-foo-foo',
    '7010102' => 'foo-foo-bar',
    '7020101' => 'bar-foo-foo',
    '7020201' => 'bar-bar-foo',
);

# The array you want
$buffer = array();

# Loop through the deepest elements (here: commune)
foreach ($c as $key => $value) {
  # Find the keys for the parent groups
  $province_key = substr($key, 0, 3);
  $district_key = substr($key, 0, 5);

  # Fill the buffer
  $buffer[$province_key][$district_key][$key] = $value; 
}

# Debug: The generated array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($buffer);
echo '</pre>';
```

You can copy&paste it [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php) and hit run.

Answer (score 0):

Test data:

```
$arrayA = [
    [
        0 => 'province',
        1 => 701,
        2 => 'AA',
        3 => 'A'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'province',
        1 => 702,
        2 => 'AA1',
        3 => 'A1'
    ],
];
$arrayB = [
    [
        0 => 'district',
        1 => 70102,
        2 => 'BB',
        3 => 'B'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'district',
        1 => 70101,
        2 => 'BB1',
        3 => 'B1'
    ],
];
$arrayC = [
    [
        0 => 'commune',
        1 => 7010101,
        2 => 'CC',
        3 => 'C'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'commune',
        1 => 7010102,
        2 => 'CC1',
        3 => 'C1'
    ]
];
```

Solution:

```
function mergeArraysToOneOnField(array $arrayA, array $arrayB, array $arrayC, $fieldName) {
    $result = [];
    /*
    checks like
        !is_string($fieldName) && !is_integer($fieldName)
    */
    $arrayARelevantFields = array_column($arrayA, $fieldName);
    $arrayBRelevantFields = array_column($arrayB, $fieldName);
    $arrayCRelevantFields = array_column($arrayC, $fieldName);
    foreach ($arrayARelevantFields as $arrayARelevantField) {
        $arrayAFilteredRelevantField = filterArrayByStrpos($arrayBRelevantFields, $arrayARelevantField);
        foreach ($arrayAFilteredRelevantField as $arrayBRelevantField) {
            $result[$arrayARelevantField][$arrayBRelevantField] =
                filterArrayByStrpos($arrayCRelevantFields, $arrayBRelevantField)
            ;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Test run:

```
$mergedArray = mergeArraysToOneOnField($arrayA, $arrayB, $arrayC, 1);
print_r($mergedArray);
```

Test Result:

```
Array
(
    [701] => Array
        (
            [70102] => Array
                (
                )

            [70101] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 7010101
                    [1] => 7010102
                )

        )

)
```

The solution can be extended with recursion, in order to hanlde a variable number of input arrays:

```
function mergeArraysToOneOnField(array &resultArray, array $inputAarray, $field) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Output

```
Array ( [color] => green [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => a [3] => b [shape] => trapezoid [4] => 4 )
```

Comment: It's a good example for `array_merge(...)`, but not a solution for the problem described in the question. -1